# Horizontal bar chart in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to draw a horizontal bar chart using chart.js 2.3.0 -

```
 var MeSeContext = document.getElementById("MeSeStatusCanvas").getContext("2d");
    var MeSeData = {
        labels: [
            "ME",
            "SE"
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Test",
                data: [100, 75],
                backgroundColor: ["#669911", "#119966" ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: ["#66A2EB", "#FCCE56"]
            }]
    };

var MeSeChart = new Chart(MeSeContext, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: MeSeData,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }]
        }

    }
});
```

But it only shows one bar. What did I miss here?

Comment: Which version of Chart.js are you using?

Comment: @TiesonT. - I've updated the question my version information.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can see only one chart because the lowest value of your data (*75 here*) is the scale's left limit.

As shown in the following screenshot of your code's result, if you hover on the scale, you can still see the associated data, which means it is here.

[image]

---

You have two ways to fix this :

- Set the `min` property of the xScale ticks to the value you want (enough to see it of course) :

  ```js
  var MeSeChart = new Chart(MeSeContext, {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      data: MeSeData,
      options: {
          scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      min: 60 // Edit the value according to what you need
                  }
              }],
              yAxes: [{
                  stacked: true
              }]
          }
      }
  });
  ```

  You can see the result with a `min` set to 60 [on this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4r26box7/) :

  [image]
- Set the `beginAtZero` property to `true`, which is the same as setting `min` to 0 :

  ```js
  xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
      }
  }],
  ```

  You can see the result with the `beginAtZero` property set to `true` [on this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4r26box7/1/).

Comment: how to to hide "Test" text with color