# Chart.js Labelling - Need Two Labels on Y-axis of Horizontal Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I created a horizontal bar chart w/ chart.js and need to create two set of labels on the y-axis but can only create one.

As an example, see image below, on the y-axis I have a grouping of words 'other' and 'paper' with counts of 2 and 3 respectively; in that grouping and the two below I also need to display the month associated with those two words - like May.

Is there a way to do this?

P.S.
In the image attached I have mirroring set to true but am open to turning mirroring off if the solution will give me the output I need.

So far I have reviewed these pages and tried using the labelString option:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html

[Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart with Two Y Axis Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196819/horizontal-stacked-bar-chart-with-two-y-axis-issues)

[Horizontal bar chart in chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254027/horizontal-bar-chart-in-chart-js)

[image: image of current state]

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I resolved this issue by using labelString - see [chart.js docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html) for details.

In particular:

```
yAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            display: true,    
                            mirror: true,                               
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: [
                                    var0+'                  '+
                                    var1+'                  '+
                                    var2
                        ]
                        }
                    }]
```

This is a bit of a hack as I needed to add 18 spaces between var0 and var1 but reviewed on multiple devices and it works.

If someone else found a different solution please share. If not, I hope this helps someone.

Image of update below - with months now on the y-axis: 
[image]